# AuraClientService.postProcess: error in processing [RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded] - Client Side Action

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, slds

I have a lightning component that is using **ui:inputSelect**.

The component code:

```
            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                <ui:inputSelect class="slds-select" aura:id="quals" change="{!c.getPreCodes}">
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.questions}" var="q">
                         <ui:inputSelectOption aura:id="question" text="{!q.Id}" label="{!q.Question_Text__c}"/>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </ui:inputSelect>
            </div>
```

The controller:

```
    getPreCodes : function(cmp, event, helper){
        var selected = cmp.find("quals").get("v.value");

        var action = cmp.get("c.getPreCodes");
        action.setParams({
            "qualID" : selected
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {

                console.log('precodes: ', response.getReturnValue());

            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
```

The basic logic is that the uiSelect is dynamically populated on init (this works fine). When a user makes a selection the "change" parameter function is fired to retrieve a list from the database and pass it to another component.

However, the change function **{!c.getPreCodes}** seems to be called recursively causing a

> "Something has gone wrong. AuraClientService.postProcess: error in
>   processing [RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded] . Please try
>   again."

error. If I comment out the **enqueueAction** the function only runs once (nothing is called recursively) so I suspect it has something to do with the controller call.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As per the doc, it is recommended to use different names for the client side and server side methods/actions.

> Use unique names for client-side and server-side actions in a
>   component. A JavaScript function (client-side action) with the same
>   name as a server-side action (Apex method) can lead to hard-to-debug
>   issues.

So all you need to do is, change your client-side controller's method  `getPreCodes` to something like `getPreCodeData`